# Convert C# 2008 files to C# 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-project

I've got a program which i made on one machine in which i used C# 9 to make it in and i now want to run it on my other machine which uses C# 2010. I opened the program in C# 2010 and use the embedded converter but it comes up with a problem. After conversion i can't debug the program as it comes up with the error 'Source file 'C:\Users\Chris\Documents\FlashCards\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs' could not be opened ('Unspecified error ') FlashCards'
What do i need to do to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as C# 9 nor C# 2010. The latest version is C# 4.0.

Comment: First find out what versions you really have, its probably form C#2 or C#3 to C#4. And check if that file exists (in your solution and on disk)

Comment: I'm guessing he means VS 2008 (C# 2008). Can you open the AssemblyInfo.cs file in notepad and/or VS?

Comment: Can you post your assmeblyinfo.cs?

Comment: C# 9 is where you no longer need to do any programming yourself, you just look at your computer and everything is auto-generated async!

Answer (score 2):

The error you got is a COM error, E_FAIL.  It is a miserable "can't make it work, don't know why" kind of error.  Visual Studio is prone to this kind of error when it wasn't installed correctly.  Especially when one of its 'packages' wasn't registered correctly.  The C# IDE is one of those packages, more than one actually.

You'll need to get your machine stable again and re-install VS2010.  Ask questions about problems with your machine's registry at superuser.com